# belongs_to association loaded individually even after eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2, eager-loading

I have the below association

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end
```

And in my PicturesController i am eager loading the user

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pictures = Picture.includes(:user).all
  end
end
```

In my view, i am displaying each pictures user name

```
-@pictures.each do |picture| 
  %tr
    %td= picture.name
    %td= picture.user.name
```

Now the question is, even though i am eager loading the user, i see individual queries fired while displaying the user name in the view.

I have around 1000 picture records and i have more than 1000 queries fired for this request.
What am i doing wrong? How do i avoid individual queries for user?

Comment: you're not doing anything wrong - is that all the code ?

Comment: Yeah. I did some testing in console and what i found was interesting. when i do `Picture.find(:all, :include => :user)` in the controller and picture.user["name"] in the view, i don't see those individual queries

Comment: try remove the `.all` it's not needed anyway (.each will trigger the sql request). You can also use the inverse_of option on your association macros. However the culprit is somewhere else

Comment: I found this bug report https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3455-ar-belongs_to-include-option-doesnt-do-anything. It looks like a bug in rails 3.

Comment: Is this still an issue for Rails 3? I'm using 3.2.21 and I'm getting the same issue as @Vimsha.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only displaying the user's name, how about grabbing it in the query along with an inner join?

Query:

```
@pictures = Picture.select("pictures.*, users.name as user_name").joins(:user).all
```

View:

```
- @pictures.each do |picture| 
  %tr
    %td= picture.name
    %td= picture.user_name
```